# Best way of listing objects in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm struggling to figure out if my method of listing objects in JSON is correct/efficient. I'm creating an API that will let the user search for engines in various ways and get info on them. So each "engine" object has several key/value pairs with it, and each "engine" is different. My current format is this:

```
{
    "engines": [
        {
            "name": "Ford Modular Engine 3-valve",
            "maker": "Ford",
            "cam": "SOHC"
        },
        {
            "name": "LS6",
            "maker": "Chevy",
            "cam": "OHV"
        }
    ]
}
```

My concern with this format is accessing a specific engine as it is hidden under an array.

The other format idea I had was this (but I'm not sure if this is "proper" syntax for a JSON object)

```
{
    "engines": {
        "ford3v": {
            "name": "Ford Modular Engine 3-valve",
            "maker": "Ford",
            "cam": "SOHC"
        },
        "ls6": {
            "name": "LS6",
            "maker": "Chevy",
            "cam": "OHV"
        }
    }
}
```

Do the differences come down to personal preference? What is the industry standard?

Comment: if you have a list of similar objects (of the same type, such as an engine), then conventionally you'd use a list - i.e. an array. In what way are you worried that this data would somehow be "hidden"?

Comment: How big is/will be the JSON data?

Comment: My concern of the data being hidden would be searching through the array for a specific engine, but thinking about it I could just loop through the whole array of engines are check on each item for a specific criteria.

Comment: In my opinion both of them are ok, the most interesting parameter to take in your choice is how you want to use this object. Will you just iterate them and here the first one is appropriate, on a second point would you search for an engine on a specific key or exclude someones and the last one is probably most interesting.
As a thought maybe this question should be post on Code Review ?

Comment: Note: This is not related but you could use JsonPath if you are looking for a filtered extraction from the JSON data

Comment: @EnfantSauvage  
So the first option would work if I wanted the API consumer to search for example by "maker" and then I could just to loop through my array and return all the engines with the the "maker" type that matches the consumers request?

Comment: @DoubleElite Both could be used in this case. But i see what's not clear for you, let imagine you are listing all your car engines, and for each car there is a link to its specific sheet. Well it will be easier to store on each `<a />` tag the `data-index`, let say `data-index="ford3v"` and to display the name as a link. It will permit you to directly get into your **ford3v** datas only by this index,  `engines["ford3v"]`. If you had used the first one, you would be obligated to compare all your `name` properties which would get more time to go on. Am I in accordance with your question ?

Comment: @DoubleElite in both way you could search on `maker` and get all those occurences, what would change is just the way to run through your object, it's not that much changes.

Comment: @EnfantSauvage Yeah that makes sense. If I wanted to get a specific engine from the "engines" object using an array would require me to loop through the whole array where if I use the second approach I could reference a specific engine object by the name like "ford3v". It seems like it comes down to how I plan to search my data. The JSON formatting is decided by how my data will be sorted and what I plan to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

In maximum cases option will be upto your requirement. It is better to have the following format because, it will be easy for you if you want to repeat the list in your html.

```
{
    "engines": [
        {
            "name": "Ford Modular Engine 3-valve",
            "maker": "Ford",
            "cam": "SOHC"
        },
        {
            "name": "LS6",
            "maker": "Chevy",
            "cam": "OHV"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the first option, because your search API implies it'll be a list of engine objects coming back. With JSON, I tend to think of objects as key-value pairs for known properties, so it's more straightforward to iterate over a list and know to look for properties on those objects to do any filtering.

Not knowing the specific case you're writing this API for, I don't believe that consumers know to look for specific engines by the key/property you provide in the second example, especially if it's merely duplicating a field (name) already present in the object.

Comment: So the first option would work if I wanted the API consumer to search for example by "maker" and then I could just to loop through my array and return all the engines with the the "maker" type that matches the consumers request?

Comment: How you process an API request is a different problem from how you format the data to return. This is more answering your processing question, but depending on the scale of your array then doing a full array iteration for each request/query might not be feasible.

Comment: Good point about processing my data vs formatting, thanks. The search API would return a list of engines based on a consumers query for a specific "marker" or "cam". But it seems like if I used either the first or second approach doesn't matter as I'd still need to loop over every engine to filter by those properties. The benefit of the second approach would be if I wanted to find a specific engine I could reference it by a name without having to search an entire array

Comment: The second approach would support using the response object like a dictionary, whereas the first would not. Again, depends on how you plan on making use of the API.